# How to keep chocolate from melting when bringing it for a flight?

Tags: hand-luggage, gifts, souvenirs

I'm thinking of bringing chocolate for my friends in my flight a month from now.

Should I keep it with the check in baggage? Or with my carry on?

Assume that weight isn't an issue - all I need to ensure is to keep it from melting.

Comment: Dry ice (solid CO2) and substantial insulation will allow vrey long cold periods - I'd expect 1+ day would be feasible in luggage. Dry Ice is allowed to be carried but airline rules may require it to be carry on only - check in advance.

Comment: FWIW - the ability to legally carry dry ice is a stupidity as it is potentially far more dangerous than various other substances which are banned or generally disapproved of. As in most areas, rules and checks aare mainly intended or able to stop honest people doing bad things. Competent bad guys would have no great problems with current restrictions.

Comment: I guess as long as you don't put it into your pant pockets, you're fine either way.

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in checked baggage, as the cargo area is usually colder than the passenger compartment.

Comment: I would keep it in hand luggage, as you know where you keep your bag and you never know what they do with your checked luggage.